# Union of Polygons with slightly shifted coordinates

Tags: postgis, union

I am trying to join some polygons using ST_Union but I am facing some problems due to slightly shifted coordinates of the polygons.

Here's an small example of two polygons I would like to merge:
[image: polygon_screen]

The problem is that the lower point does not have the same longitude in the two polygons, in the first polygon it's 8.541902841855**28**, in the second one it's 8.541902841855**22**.

Due to this marginal difference St_Union returns a MultiPolygon instead of a Polygon.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Something like the st_exteriorring (which doesn't work with MultiPolygons)?

St_ConcaveHull does not work due to some quite complicated polygons.

Comment: It's not actually possible to store *every* real value in computer representation. Your conflict is past the representation limit of an 8-byte float (and at a precision measured in angstroms). There is nothing to fix.

Comment: @Vince: actually that might be an option, cutting of the last few decimals during the import. According to wikipedia 9 decimals is an accuracy of 0.11mm, therefore it's totally unnecessary to have 14 decimals.
So the solution would be ST_SnapToGrid, will try this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Vince for the hint.

Just added rounding (PostGIS: ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 0.000000001)) to my query and now it get's recognized as one polygon.

Downside of this is that my accuracy of the borders of the polygons is now 0.1 millimeter instead of 1 nanometer, but that's totally okay.